# What happens when multiple blocks are added at the same time to a blockchain?

Tags: fork, blockchain, race-condition

I understand that something called a **‘fork’** occurs when t**wo blocks are formed at the same time**. As I managed to gather from googling, this means that two separate blockchains are created.

Wikipedia describes "fork" as *"what happens when a blockchain diverges into two potential paths forward"*, it mentions several different types of forks and explains that:

*"Accidental fork happens when two or more miners find a block at nearly the same time. The fork is resolved when subsequent block(s) are added and one of the chains becomes longer than the alternative(s). The network abandons the blocks that are not in the longest chain (they are called orphaned blocks)."*

> Skipping all the different fork types (accidental, intentional, hard,
>   soft,...), what actually happens in case of a "race condition"? Which
>   block is added first? How is the problem resolved? If two chains are
>   created, how are they later combined? Is one block simply abandoned?

Comment: Nodes will accept the longest chain as the source of truth (the one with the most proof of work). If a miner wants to accept another chain, they are taking the risk that no one will value the coins on their forked chain, so their work will be wasted.

Comment: What happens with the shorter chain? Could you get into more details: what do you mean by "the most proof of work"? and what by "no one will value coins on their forked chain"? And could we talk about blockchain in general, not focusing on bitcoins. :)

Comment: The shorter chain is simply discarded by any nodes who knew about it. Proof of work is well defined in the bitcoin white paper, it’s a large topic I would read that. Coins on a orphaned chains are worthless. First you have to define blockchain, so we have the same starting point.

Comment: I have a related sub-question: During mining, do every nodes create the same block (ie, same list of unconfirmed transactions)?

Answer (score 0):

> Skipping all the different fork types (accidental, intentional, hard,
>   soft,...), what actually happens in case of a "race condition"? Which
>   block is added first? How is the problem resolved? If two chains are
>   created, how are they later combined? Is one block simply abandoned?

Miners are always switching chains to attempt to work on the longest blockchain as this will likely be the main chain and result in higher rewards. Occasionally, like you pointed out two competing chains will fork off and they will be like this until one chain becomes longer resulting in the miners switching to this chain and the abandoned chain becoming an orphaned block.

[image: Example picture of forking]

Comment: Thank you! That I understood, but what happens with the shorter block? It can't just be thrown away? Let's forget about bitcoins and talk about blockchain in general. e.g. a bank keeps it's transactions in a blockchain and every transaction is equally important. T1 -> T2 -> T3 and then T4 and T5 happening at the same time. How will the chain look after let's say 20 transactions (T20)?

Comment: The chain just gets abandoned and is viewed as an orphan block this doesn’t mean that there are lost transactions as they will be mined in the main chain already because it is longer. When a chain forks you essentially get miners working on same transactions in different chains they are just mining to make there chain the longest to be accepted by all miners by consensus rules

Comment: Also, @joshua-duxbury, how are "original" and "forked" chains defined? Let's there's a race condition between two blocks, how is it decided which one of these gets in the "original" chain?

Comment: I found this "In the case of a valid transaction existing on an orphan block, they are added to the next valid block accepted on the blockchain" (https://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/orphan-block-cryptocurrency.asp), but I still don't understand, when does the "join" happen? When is the orphan block accepted? Does it mean that the block with the larger share of POW gets added to the original, and right after the second block participation in the race condition?

Comment: @SabinaOrazem i suppose the node with the shorter chain can just resubmit the valid orphans' transactions to the longer chain. making the longest chain even longer. if every node does this, they will eventually end up with one valid chain that has every transaction. i'm just speculating though. there could be a horrible flaw in this logic. of course this would change the block number of the said transactions but i think they shouldn't complain.

Comment: @SabinaOrazem there is no "join". The longest blockchain is accepted and shorter ones are discarded. But won't that mean the longest blockchain can potentially miss some transactions? No, there won't really be lost transactions neither because even though some tx's have been added to a shorter blockchain the tx may be pending in mempool or already added to the longest. No "join" is necessary.